# bypassing UIImagePicker in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

From my understanding on iphone sdk, the app runs in a sandbox & the only way to get access to photo library is thru the UIImagePicker. Wondering if there is any way to bypass UIImagePicker & still get all the images from the user's photo library.

I am looking for something like java's File API. (If we want list all files in a dir, as we can use dir.list() .. do we have anything similar to this in iphone sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSFileManager` to access the contents of `/User/Media/DCIM/` directly, but it's likely that Apple will reject applications that do this.